# What is the best practice for working with files and paths?

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a python script that essentially  takes a 'path to a file' as an argument by the user. It does some post processing and creates a new file in the same directory as the original file.

For example:  `myscript.py  C:\\A\\sub_A\\work_on_this_file.csv`

I'm using the path I received itself to create a File Handler for
`C:\\A\\sub_A\\final_file.csv`

I've been told to use `os.chdir()` to navigate to the folder instead and create my final file there instead of using paths directly. What is the best practice in such a scenario? Is there a risk in not changing the working directory?

Answer (score 4):

I would encourage you to *always* use absolute paths, in practice that's the most straightforward way. So, directly creating a file (or opening an existing one, doesn't matter) using the absolute path is fine.

When you are not sure whether you will have an absolute or relative path I woul suggest taking the script's directory as the base folder and then generating an absolute path, like so:

```
import os

cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
given_path = "../../myfile.csv"
csv_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, given_path))
```

Instead of `__file__` use `sys.argv[0]` when dealing with modules/imported scripts. IMO changing the CWD is normally not required and will most likely break other things soon or later.

Comment: I would further suggest logging all those paths, if feasible, but yes.  I have no idea why you would be encouraged to use os.chdir(), except to work around some legacy issue with a third-party product.

Answer (score 2):

My five cents there:

- Use [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to work with CSV Files
- Use 
  [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)
  statement upon opening files, in that case file would always be
  closed in case of any unexpected error.
- Always use [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep)
  in order to have cross platform paths.
- Use
  [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
  to form file path correctly.
- Use
  [os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep)
  when it's possible, to process file line by line correctly.